# Display data according to text field value using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a issue.I want to fetch data from data base according to text field value.This text field will take two types of value.First one is simple number(e.g-123456789) and second one is like this(e.g-123456789/1).The simple number is present in DB for one table.In the second one number after "/" (i.e-1) is another table's id which is associated with first table.Then my aim is when user will give the input "123456789" the data will fetch according to this number by searching and when user will give the input "123456789/1" first it will split the number and values will be fetched according to both number and id (i.e-123456789 and 1) from the both table.

Here i am explaining some of my code below.

## homes/hcsy_html.erb

```
<% if current_admin %>
<div class="header">
<div class="navbar-header">Swargadwar, Puri Municipality,govt of odisha</div>
<div class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
<div class="image"></div>
</div>
<div class="name-div">

</div>
</div>
<div class="menu-div">
<div id="leftsidebtn">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="/homes/registration">Create User</a></li>
   <li><a href="/homes/hcsy">Scan Report</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">View and Payment Report</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="/homes/hcsy">HCSY</a></li>

   </ul>
  </li>

   <li><a href="#">Payment Validate</a></li>
   <li><a href="/sessions/removeadmin">Log Out</a></li>
 </ul>  
</div>
</div>
<div class="content-div">
    Logged in as:<%= current_admin.email %>
    <center><h1>HARICHANDRA SAHAYATA YOJANA SLIP</h1></center>
    <%= form_for :hcsy,:url => {:action =>'scan_hcsy' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :reciept,placeholder:"Get your scan code",:onchange => 'this.form.submit();' %>
    <% end %>
  <% if params[:id] %>
<center><h1>HARICHANDRA SAHAYATA YOJANA SLIP</h1></center>
  Receipt No :<%= @hcsys.Receipt_No %>
    <div class="left-content">
<p>Deceased Name :</p> <%= @hcsys.Deceased_Name %>
<p>Beneficary name :</p> <%= @hcsys.Beneficiary_Name %>
<p>Relation with Deceased :</p> <%= @hcsys.Beneficiary_Rel_With_Decease %>
<p>Address :</p> <%= @hcsys.Address %>
<p>Police station :</p> <%= @hcsys.PoliceStation %>
<p>Mobile No :</p> <%= @hcsys.Mobile_No %>
<p>Occupation :</p> <%= @hcsys.Occupation %>
<p>Brahmin :</p> <%= @hcsys.Brahmin %>
<p>Amount Required :</p> <%= @hcsys.Amount_Required %>
<p>Has He/She recieved any assistance erlier from this fund :</p> <%= @hcsys.Recieved_Fund_Earlier %>
</div>
<div class="right-content">
<p>BPL :</p> <%= @hcsys.BPL %>
<p>Govt. Service :</p> <%= @hcsys.Govt_Service %>
<p>Business :</p> <%= @hcsys.Business %>
<p>Land of property :</p> <%= @hcsys.Land_Property %>
<p>Other :</p> <%= @hcsys.Others %>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

## controller/homes_controller.rb

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
    def index

    end
    def registration
        @user=User.new
    end
    def usersave
        @admin=Admin.find(params[:id])
        @user=User.new(params[:user])
        @user.admin_id=@admin.id
        if @user.save
            flash[:notice]="User has created successfully"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => "index"
        else
            flash[:alert]="User could not created"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'registration'
        end
    end
    def hcsy_reg
        @hcsy=THcsy.new
    end
    def create_reg
        @hcsy=THcsy.new(params[:hcsy])
        if @hcsy.save
            flash[:notice]="Data has saved successfully"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => "hcsy_details",:id1 => params[:id],:id2 => @hcsy.id
        else
            flash[:alert]="Data could not saved successfully"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'hcsy_reg'
        end
    end
    def scan_hcsy
         @hcsy=THcsy.find_by_Receipt_No(params[:hcsy][:reciept])
            if @hcsy
                flash[:notice]="Check the record"
                flash[:color]="valid"
                redirect_to :action => 'hcsy',:id => @hcsy.id
            else
                flash[:alert]="Receipt number could not found"
                flash[:color]="invalid"
                render 'hcsy'
            end


    end
    def hcsy
        if params[:id]
        @hcsys=THcsy.find(params[:id])
    end
    end
    def scanrecord
        @hcsy=THcsy.find(params[:id])
    end
    def hcsy_deatils
        @t_hcsy=THcsyFundTypeMaster.new
    end
    def create_details
        @t_hcsy=THcsyFundTypeMaster.new(params[:t_hcsy])
        if @t_hcsy.save
            flash[:notice]="Check the record"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => 'hcsy_details_master',:id1 => params[:id1] ,:id2 => params[:id2] , :id3 => @t_hcsy.HCSY_Fund_Type_ID 
        else
            flash[:alert]="Receipt number could not found"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'hcsy_deatils'
        end
    end
    def hcsy_details_master
        @t_hcsy_master=THcsyDetails.new
    end
    def create_details1
        @admin=Admin.find(params[:id1])
        @hcsy=THcsy.find(params[:id2])
        @t_hcsy=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_HCSY_Fund_Type_ID(params[:id3])
        @t_hcsy_master=THcsyDetails.new(params[:t_hcsy_master])
        @t_hcsy_master.Created_By=@admin.id
        @t_hcsy_master.HCSY_ID=@hcsy.id
        @t_hcsy_master.HCSY_Fund_Type_ID=@t_hcsy.HCSY_Fund_Type_ID
        if @t_hcsy_master.save
            flash[:notice]="Record has created"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => 'index'
        else
            flash[:alert]="Record could not create"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'hcsy_details_master'
        end

    end
end
```

Here i have done for simple number please help me to fetch data from both table by the second input number(i.e-123456789/1).For this all operations are executing inside "scan_hcsy" method.Atleast help me to split the number(i.e-123456789/1) to 123456789 and 1 so that i can fetch data according to this number and id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string, which results into an Array:

```
"12345678/1".split('/')
=> ["12345678", "1"]
```

In your case:

```
splitted = params[:hcsy][:reciept].split('/')
hcys = splitted[0]
table_id = splitted[1]
```